What is the intended or interpreted usage of 'to infinitive' in a sentence?

The built­-in capacity for smiling is proven by the remarkable observation that babies who are congenitally both deaf and blind, who have never seen a human face, also start to smile at around 2 months. However, smiling in blind babies eventually disappears if nothing is done to reinforce it. Without the right feedback, smiling dies out. But here’s a fascinating fact: blind babies will continue to smile if they are cuddled, bounced, nudged, and tickled by an adult ― anything to let them know that they are not alone and that someone cares about them. This social feedback
encourages the baby to continue smiling. In this way, early experience operates with our biology to establish social behaviors. In fact, you don’t need the cases of blind babies to make the point. Babies with sight smile more at you when you look at them or, better still, smile back at
them.

What's the usage of "to establish social behaviors" in the sentence "In this way, early experience operates with our biology to establish social behaviors."?
'adjectival' usage which modifies 'our biology' or 'adverbial' which modifies 'operates with our biology'?

Short answer: it signals for the purpose of or intention.

The babies' early experience works together with our (humans') biology to make them behave in certain ways.

It makes no sense to associate to establish... with our biology. That would imply the purpose of "our biology" is to establish social behaviors, which is daft.

In a context like Britain is cooperating with American policies to eradicate terrorism it's ambiguous whether the highlighted "adverb of purpose" specifically applies to preceding American policies or (as a "whole sentence adverb") to the entire preceding assertion. But the first possibility wouldn't make sense if we changed policies to politicians.

I'd say it's ambiguous between a purpose and a result adjunct.

I'd say In this way and to establish social behaviors both function as "whole sentence adverb" components in the cited text. And I don't think it would make much if any difference if they exchanged places, or were both placed consecutively at the beginning or the end of the utterance.

What's the meaning of biology? Smile?

In my personal interpretation, built-in capacity for smiling = our biology to establish social behaviors, meaning 'our biology to establish': adjectival usage.

BilJ: I respect your opinion.


...early experience operates with our biology to establish social behaviors.

Since experience cannot have a purpose in mind, it just happens, I'd say that  to establish social behaviors expresses a result there.
It's a case where the passive would be a good choice:

Social behaviors are established when repeated experiences reinforce our biology.



In this way, early experience operates with our biology to establish social behaviors.

The infinitive to establish social behaviors is adverbial and modifies the verb phrase operates with our biology.  It answers 'For what purpose?'
